# Как из масива вытащить нужное поле?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [success] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [ApplicationId] => 3259
            [ClientExist] => 0
            [DecisionResult] => PREACCEPTED
            [AutoFill_Result] => 1
            [AutoFill_MaritalStatusId] => 1
            [AutoFill_EducationId] => 2
            [AutoFill_NumberOfChildren] => 1
            [AutoFill_NumberOfAdults] => 2
            [AutoFill_TypeOfResidenceId] => 1
            [AutoFill_CarExistence] => 0
            [AutoFill_HomePhone] => 77271212121
            [AutoFill_LivingRegionId] => 6
            [AutoFill_LivingDistrictId] => 601
            [AutoFill_LivingSameRegistration] => 1
            [AutoFill_RegistrationRegionId] => 6
            [AutoFill_RegistrationDistrictId] => 601
            [AutoFill_WorkExperienceId] => 2
            [AutoFill_EmploymentTypeId] => 1
            [AutoFill_EmployeeName] => ТОО Чебурашка
            [AutoFill_EmployeeActivitySphereId] => 1
            [AutoFill_WorkPhone] => 77012345678
            [AutoFill_MonthlyIncome] => 120000
            [AutoFill_BusinessActivitySphereId] => 2
            [AutoFill_BusinessMonthlyProceeds] => 200000
            [AutoFill_BusinessNetProfit] => 100000
            [AutoFill_BusinessAddIncome] => 150000
            [AutoFill_BusinessCurrentExperienceId] => 2
            [AutoFill_BusinessTotalExperienceId] => 3
            [AutoFill_NumberOfActiveLoans] => 2
            [AutoFill_OtherCreditsCharges] => 10000
            [AutoFill_OtherCreditsOverdueFlag] => 0
            [AutoFill_OtherCreditsOverdue] => 0
            [AutoFill_Contact1FullName] => Омаров Омар
            [AutoFill_Contact1Phone] => 77012345678
            [AutoFill_Contact1RelationshipId] => 1
            [AutoFill_Contact2FullName] => Тестов Тест
            [AutoFill_Contact2Phone] => 77014441421
            [AutoFill_Contact2RelationshipId] => 2
        )

)
```

как из этого массива вытащить это поле [DecisionResult] ??

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите вытащить, что за "введите сюда код"?

Comment: array['data']['DecisionResult']

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php - раздел "Доступ к элементам массива".

Comment: Спс вопрос решен

Answer (score 2):

```
$array["data"]["DecisionResult"]
```